# Extract value of data blob ins pgsql

Tags: database, postgresql

I have one blob table having data like this -

```
Kelly~..$Sather~..$THE BODEN~..$~..$425-a~..$~..$Current~..$kelly.j.sather_ndus.edu@r.com~..$~..$111-111-1111~..$111-111-1111~..$
```

From this data, I want *Current* value only. How to extract data rom this row value.

Comment: Can you define what the *Current* value is?

Comment: From the string, I want to extract Current keyword only.

Comment: Exactly. What *is* the current keyword? Maybe add the desired result to the question.